# Using NSNotificationCenter as a central action router/dispatcher

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

One of my colleagues suggested using NSNotificationCenter as some sort of central router/dispatcher in our iOS app. So if we want to transition from one view controller to another, we can do this by just sending a notification (optionally with some userInfo to initialize the destination view controller) which an action dispatcher singleton class will catch and do the transitioning work (mostly navigation controller pushes). There are a couple of places in our app from which you can jump to the same view controller (showing a detailed view of an entity). With this approach we could have this in one place and trigger it easily.

Is this a good idea? Can you think of any drawbacks, maybe even major trouble down the road?

Comment: I dont see the need why you are making a star structure with your singolton at center rather then following linear structure which is more natural to navigation stack?

Comment: The action dispatcher does more than just a push on the navigation stack. It also loads the entity from a REST API that is to be displayed by the destination view controller, complete with a loading indicator and stuff like that and we don't want to copy this code around.

Comment: I dont know your full app so best bet will be you decide on 1.Scalability 2.ease of change 3.Memory and speed. I usually have a serverbuddy class which has got all web services and through its method i interact with REST api from my destination viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a scenario where you mostly work in a state-machine-like processing style using the notification center as central hub is a good idea. The receiver can maintain a navigation stack easily and trigger changes caused by the user navigating back/forward to the notification center easily as well.

An advantage of this paradigm is that neither part of the app needs to know the other parts (unless they need their service directly), which can simplify the structure if you have a big application.

A drawback might be that the communication between the various parts can be confusing for programmers starting new with that code. Depends of course on the level of knowlege of that person.